# How to fix " No such file or directory"error when I access to the home page

Tags: laravel

I downloaded a laravel project from a shared hosting and I want to edit him in my localhost but when I type out the home adress:
localhost:8000/
it shows me those two errors :

> Warning: require_once(C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea\server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Rafaa\Downloads\Compressed.idea\server.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

When you clone or download a project from somewhere, there may be a case that many dependencies like codes or library files are missing. To solve this

1. Open the terminal
2. Go to the directory where the project folder is situated.
3. RUN **composer install**

If it still does not work, 
RUN **composer update**

That should do the trick.

Comment: Do you use any Antivirus? It often removes the server.php file. Disable the antivirus and follow the above processes again.

Comment: No mate I don't use any anti-virus and the server.php exist

Comment: Add the server.php file in your root directory